# Do you precompile your website and why/why not?

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I'd like to get the pulse of the community on whether to precompile or not.  I know its cold start time is faster, and it hides code.  However, there is something *dirty* about it, IMO.  Maybe its the name, compiling a website sounds incorrect.

In general how are you deploying web apps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i only precompile websites that are sold and licensed commercially, in order to protect the source code from modification.

supposedly this benefits performance, but that is secondary; it's nearly impossible to rationally support a commercial web site product if anyone can muck with the code!

Answer (score 8):

Okay I have two answers depending on the situation:

- **Situation 1**: I am deploying and I will continue to deploy upgrades.  I use the copy method.  It's simpler for me, I know what I'm doing and that way I don't have to write an installer.
- **Situation 2**: An unknown party [i.e. the client] with unknown skill is going to be attempting to deploy my site, I write an installer and documentation an 8 year old can follow on going through the installer right through to configuration - and if necessary data input.  So in this situation the precompiled method is far easier.

So I don't use either religiously, I pick the most appropriate method for the situation.

Answer (score 3):

We use the precompiled approach on my team because we have to hand off the deployment to the infrastructure team.  We build an MSI package (with a web deployment project) that installs the new release to the website.

It's more of a separation of duties/responsibilities thing that drives our methodology though, nothing technical.

Answer (score 3):

Having the source code laying around on Production servers is generally a bad plan. Taking the pre-compiled approach feels a bit safer :)

Our pre-compiled web site gets built into an MSI package that is used for deployment to a clustered environment.

Answer (score 2):

I use precompiled, updateable web sites exclusively for ASP.NET web forms.

Answer (score 1):

In our case precompiling found us some pages that did not compile.

So I'd reccommend doing a precompile during the build, but not necessarily deploing it.

Answer (score 0):

We do not deploy our websites precompiled.

**Reason**: "that's how we did it the first time and it hasn't broken yet."

Comment: why arent you programming in traditional asp?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're getting at with your question.